# How to change string output colour

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got a function. How can I add colours to the outputs? For example, if it's too low. I want orange, if it says obese, I want it to be red.

```
bmiCalculation() {
      var weight = parseInt(this.currentWeight);
      var height = parseInt(this.height) / 100;
      var bmi = weight / (height * height);
      let text = "";
      if (bmi < 18.5) {
        text =  bmi.toFixed(2) + "kg/m2" + " Too low :)";
      } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
        text =  bmi.toFixed(2) + "kg/m2" + " Normal";
      } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 29.9) {
        text =  bmi.toFixed(2) + "kg/m2" + " Too much";
      } else if (bmi > 30) {
        text =  bmi.toFixed(2) + "kg/m2" + " Obese";
      }

      return text;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to change the output color of the console.log if you log or in html?

Comment: what's the output? is it console? is it htmlElement?

Comment: html,               h5.bmi.font-weight-bold {{ bmiCalculation }} I use vuejs

Comment: @Dave Please post the code where you want to bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var STATUSES = {
  LOW: {
    message: 'Too low ;)',
    color: 'red',
  },
  NORMAL: {
    message: 'Normal',
    color: 'green',
  },
  HIGHER_THAN_NORMAL: {
    message: 'Too Much',
    color: 'orange',
  },
  OBESE: {
    message: 'Obese',
    color: 'red',
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentWeight: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    bmiLevelColor: '',
  },
  computed: {
    bmiCalculation() {
      var weight = parseInt(this.currentWeight, 10);
      var height = parseInt(this.height, 10) / 100;

      if (isNaN(weight) || isNaN(height)) {
        return;
      }

      if (weight <= 0 || height <= 0) {
        throw new RangeError('Weight and Height must be higher than zero.');
      }

      var bmi = weight / (height * height);
      var status;

      if (bmi < 18.5) {
        status = STATUSES.LOW;
      } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
        status = STATUSES.NORMAL;
      } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30) {
        status = STATUSES.HIGHER_THAN_NORMAL;
      } else if (bmi >= 30) {
        status = STATUSES.OBESE;
      }

      this.bmiLevelColor = status.color;

      return bmi.toFixed(2) + "kg/m2 " + status.message;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  currentWeight <input v-model="currentWeight" />
  height <input v-model="height" />
  <div :style="{ color: bmiLevelColor }">{{ bmiCalculation }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your text in an HTML element (span), and set CSS (color) to it.

Comment: I use vue js               h5.bmi.font-weight-bold {{ bmiCalculation }}

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a style sheet with the colors and styles you want..  Then use the add.classlist in javascript or something similar to add different classes to the output depending on it's value.